# What is the biggest bitcoin transaction ever performed so far?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

What is the biggest bitcoin transaction ever performed so far (by value at the time of transaction)? And what was its transaction fee?

Comment: Are you asking by value or by number of bitcoins?

Comment: @Murch by BTC's value at the time of transaction